# How to turn off "dangerous Request.Path" validation while using requestValidationMode="4.5"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, runtime-error

When I use requestValidationMode="2.0" then I able to prevent ASP.NET framework from running "dangerous Request.Path" validation.

Here's the web.config line that solves it:

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" requestPathInvalidCharacters="" maxRequestLength="8192" />
```

However I cannot make it work with requestValidationMode="4.5".

In that mode ASP.NET framework refuses to give up "dangerous Request.Path" validation.

So when I request:

```
http://localhost/PostJobFree/autocompleteskills/%3Ctest%3E
```

I'm getting crash with:

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (="...eteskills/<test>").
```

Any idea how to make it work in requestValidationMode="4.5" or should I stick with requestValidationMode="2.0"?

Comment: Is the code accessing `Request.Path` your own code or is it somewhere deep in a library?

Comment: None of my code is executed.
Crash happens during URL validation in ASP.NET framework.